# Swift "guard let" unwrap failed

Tags: xcode, swift, var, guard, let

Can't unwrap optional type with Swift 2.2, Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175)

"guard let" failed
[image: "guard let" failed]

But "guard var" works
[image: But "guard let" works]

Please, help!
What is going on here?

**EDIT1**

```
    let localPresenter = presenter
    let localDataSource = dataSource
    let configurator: ViewControllerConfigurator = { inputView in
        let a = inputView as? ChatTableViewController
        guard var chatListController = a else {
            throw ApplicationErrors.ModuleConfigureError.WrongViewInput
        }
        localPresenter.view = chatListController
        chatListController.presenter = localPresenter
        chatListController.tableView.dataSource = localDataSource
    }
```

**EDIT2**
This code works fine:

```
        let localPresenter = presenter
        let localDataSource = dataSource
        let configurator: ViewControllerConfigurator = { inputView in
            let a = inputView as? ChatTableViewController
            if let chatListController = a {
                localPresenter.view = chatListController
                chatListController.presenter = localPresenter
                chatListController.tableView.dataSource = localDataSource
            } else {
                throw ApplicationErrors.ModuleConfigureError.WrongViewInput
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please also include your code **as text** (use the [edit] button).

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't create a simple sample project.

Comment: @EricD Thanks, I know it, but the issue is not about the breakpoints. I can't figure out why guard unwraps the variable out well, but it can't unwrap a constant?

Comment: @EricD Thanks you point me this way with breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a bug in lldb.
If I set a breakpoint on the line with "guard" then "guard" fails:
[image]

But if I move this breakpoint past the guard block the code works fine:
[image]

Comment: It's not a bug, it's how it works. :) The breakpoint is a barrier, a stop sign: the execution runs *until it encounters the breakpoint* so if you put the stop *on* a line, the app pauses *just before this line*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why it works this way that when I set a breakpoint the code fails? What to read about his behavior? I know the breakpoint far back in the past was an IRQ to stop a CPU on an instruction, but looks like there is something happened here with register values therefore the code works wrong. Isn't it?

Comment: In physics it's called "observer effect".

Comment: @adnako have you tried not using breakpoints but `print` statements instead?

Comment: I'd like to see entire picture of program state, `print` statement is for simple logging.